# How do inject from Asp.net to a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a hard time figuring out what is wrong about my code. The purpose is to take data from a registering form in ASP to my user data columns in my SQL database.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);        

try
{
    string cmd = "insert into UserLogin 
    values(@UserName,@Password)";

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cmd);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmd, cnn);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UsernameBox.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordBox.Text);

    cnn.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);`

Comment: `what is wrong about my code` - What is wrong? Do you get any error?

Comment: I hope you're not storing passwords as plain text in the database?

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text is pretty much criminal negligence. Unless this is a school project you need to fix that immediately. Passwords should be salted and hashed. Also, AddWithValue has some pretty interesting nuances you need to careful of. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Yeah this is just a practice on how to do it, not a database that is used publicly.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the connection string in the `connection` variable but the variable you're passing to `SqlCommand` is `cnn` which doesn't have a valid connection string associated with it.

I've cleaned up your code and made use of `using` block to ensure the correct manner of disposing the object. Please see below:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   string query = "insert into UserLogin values(@UserName, @Password)";
   using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UsernameBox.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordBox.Text);

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two SqlConnection variable and assigning wrong one in the SqlCommand. The working code will be:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);        

try
{
    string cmd = "insert into UserLogin values(@UserName, @Password)";

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UsernameBox.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", PasswordBox.Text);

    cnn.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```